# Echo arrays in foreach loop codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, foreach

I've been using codeigniter for years but there's a really big gap in between so i always find myself in situations where i forgot how to do things and its almost midnight here so my brain isn't working fast. Can someone show me how to echo the array i have and explain to me how they are processed in the foreach loops?

I have this code in my model to take the rows in 2 tables.

```
public function tag_genre(){
$result['tag'] = $this->db->get('tags')->result_array();
$result['genre'] = $this->db->get('genre')->result_array();
return $result;
}
```

And I have this in my controller

```
public function view_publish_story(){
$data = array('tag_genre' => $this->story_model->tag_genre(), 'title' => "New Story");

$this->load->view('template/header',$data);
$this->load->view('template/navbar');
$this->load->view('pages/storypublish',$data);
$this->load->view('template/footer');   
}
```

I used print_r in my view and this is the result. Seeing this just confuses me more. It's been atleast 2 years since i even dealt with foreach loops.

> Array ( [tag] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [tag_id] => 1 [tag_name] =>
>   LitRPG ) [1] => Array ( [tag_id] => 2 [tag_name] => Virtual Reality )
>   [2] => Array ( [tag_id] => 3 [tag_name] => Cyberpunk ) [3] => Array (
>   [tag_id] => 4 [tag_name] => Reincarnation ) [4] => Array ( [tag_id] =>
>   5 [tag_name] => Summoned Hero ) [5] => Array ( [tag_id] => 6
>   [tag_name] => Martial Arts ) [6] => Array ( [tag_id] => 7 [tag_name]
>   => Slice of Life ) [7] => Array ( [tag_id] => 8 [tag_name] => Overpowered ) [8] => Array ( [tag_id] => 9 [tag_name] => Non-Human )
>   [9] => Array ( [tag_id] => 10 [tag_name] => Anti-hero ) ) [genre] =>
>   Array ( [0] => Array ( [genre_id] => 1 [genre_name] => action ) [1] =>
>   Array ( [genre_id] => 2 [genre_name] => adventure ) [2] => Array (
>   [genre_id] => 3 [genre_name] => comedy ) [3] => Array ( [genre_id] =>
>   4 [genre_name] => Drama ) [4] => Array ( [genre_id] => 5 [genre_name]
>   => Fantasy ) [5] => Array ( [genre_id] => 6 [genre_name] => Historical ) [6] => Array ( [genre_id] => 7 [genre_name] => Horror ) [7] => Array
>   ( [genre_id] => 8 [genre_name] => Psychological ) [8] => Array (
>   [genre_id] => 9 [genre_name] => Romance ) [9] => Array ( [genre_id] =>
>   10 [genre_name] => Sci-fi ) [10] => Array ( [genre_id] => 11
>   [genre_name] => Mystery ) [11] => Array ( [genre_id] => 12
>   [genre_name] => Tragedy ) [12] => Array ( [genre_id] => 13
>   [genre_name] => Short Story ) [13] => Array ( [genre_id] => 14
>   [genre_name] => Satire ) ) )

I've been looking at various questions regarding arrays from assoc to multidimensional and other stuff. Then i finally visited php manual for foreach loop and i finally was able to echo the array. The problem now is that although it echoes my array it also has an error for each, i can probably fix the error part by declaring it as a defined variable. My question is, is there any other better way? or any improvement on how i made my array to make it cleaner or easier to print?

```
foreach($tag_genre as $key => $value){
    foreach($value as $values){
        echo $values['tag_name'];
    }
}
```

UPDATE: i changed the way i made the array.

This is now my model:

```
public function get_tags(){
    $query = $this->db->get('tags')->result_array();

    foreach($query as $row){
    $result[$row['tag_id']] = $row['tag_name'];}
    return $result;
}

public function get_genre(){
    $query = $this->db->get('genre')->result_array();

    foreach($query as $row){
    $result[$row['genre_id']] = $row['genre_name'];}
    return $result;
}
```

and my controller:

```
public function view_publish_story(){
$data = array('tag' => $this->story_model->get_tags(), 'genre' => $this->story_model->get_genre(), 'title' => "New Story");

$this->load->view('template/header',$data);
$this->load->view('template/navbar');
$this->load->view('pages/storypublish',$data);
$this->load->view('template/footer');   
}
```

and in my view:

```
<tr>
<div class="form-group">
    <td><label for="genre">Genre</label></td>
    <?php  
    foreach($genre as $genre_id => $genre_name){
    echo "<td><label class='checkbox-inline'><input type='checkbox' value=''>".$genre_name."</label><td>";
    }
    ?>
</div>
</tr>
```

My problem now is that, how do i fit all these into my table? I just ruined my table right now since i echoed them all in a single line. How do i do it so that it is printed in 3 columns?

Comment: Well what exactly do you want to iterate over - the part set by the model? In which case in your view you'd use `foreach($tag_genre['tag']...` or `foreach($tag_genre['genre']...`.

Comment: I'm making a simple project where you can upload your own story. So in my publish story view, i have the simple form for the story. Ofcourse it contains genre and tags. I want to echo them in a foreach loop. I have saved the tags and genre in my database.

Comment: Right, and I showed you in my comment how to reference them.

Comment: Can you look at my edit. I managed to echo my array but i wanna know if there is any better way? maybe an improvement on how i made the array itself before passing it to the view to make it easier in the view to print?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($tag_genre as $key => $value){
    foreach($value as $values){
        echo '<pre>';
        echo $values['tag_name'];
    }
}
```

this will format your array in a way you can read it and understand it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function gettotalnoofsellersgraphdata()
{
    // echo 'sellers';
    // die;
    $a=0;
    $paramData = $this->input->post();
    $data = $this->cerc_form_model->gettotalnoofsellersgraphdata($paramData);
    $output=[];
    foreach($data as $row){
        $output[]=array('value'=>$row->value,'month'=>$row->monthnm);
        $a += $row->value;
    }
    $data1['output']=($output);
    echo json_encode(["status" => "SUCCESS", "msg" => "Data Loaded", "data" => $data1,"total sellers"=>$a]);
    
}
```

foreach loop in apis